# Problema al reconfigurar Nginx para SSL con certificado autofirmado

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, django-admin

Tengo un VPS en Digital Ocean con Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx, Gunicorn, Django, y una aplicación web de pruebas, configurado todo (ufw) para trabajar con http:80. Todo funciona perfectamente. [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#configure-nginx-to-proxy-pass-to-gunicorn)

Ahora modifico el archivo **/sites-available/LibrosWeb** para que permita el tráfico SSL con un certificado autofirmado, puesto que no dispongo de un dominio. [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04). Resultado **"Error 502 Bad Gateway"**.

Este es el código incial que funciona bien con http:80:

```
server{
    #Configuracion http

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 15.15.15.15;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location  /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/LibrosWeb/robots.txt ;
    }        
    location /static/ {
        root /home/gela/LibrosWeb;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Y este es el código para permitir SSL:

```
server{
    #Configuracion SSL

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name 15.15.15.15;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location  /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/LibrosWeb/robots.txt ;
    }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/gela/LibrosWeb;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

server{
    #Configuracion http

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 15.15.15.15;
    return 302 https://15.15.15.15$request_uri;
}
```

UFW configurado como:

```
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Los archivos **/etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf** y **/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf** son los mismos que los del tutorial.

Llevo dos días probando configuraciones y lo máximo que he podido conseguir es que me funcione a medias, es decir, puedo mostrar la página predetermina de django pero no la de mi aplicación, si pongo el código así:

```
server{
    #Configuracion http

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 15.15.15.15;
    return 302 https://15.15.15.15$request_uri;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location  /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/LibrosWeb/robots.txt ;
    }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/gela/LibrosWeb;
    }
}

server{
    #Configuracion SSL

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name 15.15.15.15;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass https://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal, o lo que falta?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que mis días de sufrimiento han terminado. Después de leer cientos de logs, encontré el problema. Una actualización de Whitenoise a 4.0 donde debe cambiar la forma de la configuración, provocó que con mi vieja configuración el servicio de gunicorn lanzara errores. Lo demás está todo correcto.

> http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#django-middleware

Gracias por la ayuda.
Buen día.